# Scroll lock for jface TreeViewer

Tags: swt, jface, treeviewer

Is it possible to activate a scroll lock to a Jface TreeViewer (like it is for the TableViewer)?

I am constantly adding elements to the tree. If an item is selected, this item will move downwards as new elements arrive. But once it reaches the bottom, a kind of scroll lock is activated which keeps the element in focus.

Can this be activated without selecting elements?

Comment: TreeViewer has a `reveal` method, but this is something you would have to call, There is nothing automatic.

Comment: Ok, then I'll implement it myself. Thanks for the clarification.